# How to implement custom date picker in flutter

Tags: flutter, datepicker

[image]

After clicking on Nov date picker will open with day, month and year option to choose from

Answer (score 0):

No need to implement it from scratch. Use [this](https://pub.dev/packages/horizontal_week_calendar) package and modify it to achieve the desired UI.

I modified it last month to achive this UI.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but how to get month name on the left? and on tap of it datepicker dialog will open

Comment: You will have to explore the internals of the package and make changes to it according to your need.

Comment: yes, there are couple of properties only. cant pass it datetime and make changes logically. Its not a suitable package..cant chnage year or month with it and cant disable header also

Comment: So, cool, use that source code as inspiration and code whatever you want!  Welcome to open source!